# could not locate element with visible text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[View source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODURR.jpg)When city name selected  then it has to match input campus name from the list and to be selected matched one.Below is the code and screenshot.

```
tkt_campus = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cityTicketingId')
city = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cityTicketingId')))
city.click()
t_city = Select(city)
t_city.select_by_visible_text(tkt_city_name.strip())
WebDriverWait(browser, 1)
tkt_campus = city = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'campusTicketingId')))
t_campus = Select(tkt_campus)
t_campus.select_by_visible_text(campus_name.strip())
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cLBd.jpg)

[Click to view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1aZO.jpg)

Comment: Could you add the HTML from the view page?

Comment: Added view source.. When i run through python ide console it works fine but not directly.

Comment: To clarify:the script works when you execute through a console line-by-line. It does not work when the script is executed all at once. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Exactly.....

Comment: OK. That's a pretty clear sign that the driver needs to wait for the dropdown to render...should be a simple fix, I'll put in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the script is working on the command line and not as a singular script, it's more than likely the webdriver needs to wait for the dropdown to render. There is a natural pause when you insert via command line, line-by-line, but when run as a script, the lines of code are executed instantaneously and checking for the text before it has been rendered into HTML.

All is good, except for the 2nd to last line. Looks like you've already used the WebDriverWait function once:

```
tkt_campus = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cityTicketingId')
city = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cityTicketingId')))
city.click()
t_city = Select(city)
t_city.select_by_visible_text(tkt_city_name.strip())
WebDriverWait(browser, 1)
tkt_campus = city = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'campusTicketingId')))
t_campus = Select(tkt_campus)

t_campus = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT('ELURU'))

t_campus.select_by_visible_text(campus_name.strip())
```

Comment: Can we declare wait time(condition) until it recognise the drop down list is  generated.

Comment: Getting error: 'str' object is not callable   at (WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT(campus_name))))